# Indented block in ConTeXt

Tags: context, algorithms

I need to write pseudocode in ConTeXt. Since there is no documentation of the *t-algorithmic* module, and because I don't have so much to write, I decided to format the code myself.

Here is what I tried:

```
\def\>{\space\space\space\space}

{\bf for all} $i \in [0, 43[$\\
\>  blah blah
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. How can I indent a specific line ? Or an entire paragraph.

Thanks !

Comment: [The documentation for the algorithmic module can be found on BitBucket.](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/algorithmic/src/ef4cb1b63db53732947759a880d096ba46eddbd7/files/algorithmic-1.tex) Consider using it. To your problem: You can use `\setupindenting[yes,big] \let\>\indent`. And watch out, TeX does not eat the space after the `>`.

Comment: \setupindenting adds indentation for all the paragraphs of the document, how can I avoid this ? Thanks for the documentation ! :)

Comment: Switch the indentation off after you're done with your algorithm: `\setupindenting[no]`

Comment: Also, for indenting multiple lines you can use the [``\{start,stop}narrower``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupnarrower) environment.

Comment: Thanks to both of you ! \statnarrower is exactly what I needed.

Comment: If you really want to use the minimal markup that use have, use `\def\>{\null\qquad}`.  Adding the \null ensures that the space at the beinining of the line is not eaten. Another option is to use the lines environment with `space=yes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The documentation for the algorithmic module can be found on
BitBucket.](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/algorithmic/src/ef4cb1b63db53732947759a880d096ba46eddbd7/files/algorithmic-1.tex).
Here I present three solutions, one using the `algorithmic` module, one which
uses the `lines` environment and your custom `\>` macro and one which uses the
`lines` environment combined with the `narrower` environment, which is rather
verbose.

```
\usemodule[algorithmic]
\starttext

  \subject{\mono{algorithmic:}}

  \startalgorithmic
    \FORALL {\math{i \in [0, 43[}}
      \STATE blah blah
      \STATE more lines
    \ENDFOR
  \stopalgorithmic

  \subject{\mono{lines} and custom macro:}

  \def\>{\quad}
  \startlines
    {\bf for all} \math{i \in [0, 43[}
    \>blah blah
    \>more lines
  \stoplines

  \subject{\mono{lines} and \mono{narrower}:}

  \startlines
    {\bf for all} \math{i \in [0, 43[}
    \startnarrower
      blah blah
      more lines
    \stopnarrower
  \stoplines

\stoptext
```

[image: result]